# How to use Spring-batch to read messages from Spring-integration channel?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

My existing spring-integration application dumps POJO messages to a channel. How do I hook spring-batch so it will read messages in real time from this channel? Do I need to create a custom ItemReader or is there something out-of-the-box that I can use? A simple sample XML configuration would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of anything "out of the box" but it would be trivial to wrap a `PollableChannel` (usually `Queuechannel`) in an `ItemReader`, simply use `channel.receive(timeout)` in `read()`.

When the timeout expires, the reader returns null; indicating the end of the batch.

Comment: Thanks -- it is a very good suggestion! In my situation, the channels will always get data so it seems the batch job will never end. Also, I am not sure if the 1st message on the channel will trigger the batch job, so I'll need to launch the job somehow. I read [INT-3364](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3364) where you suggested wrapping a JdbcBatchItemWriter in a service-activator to support batch insert -- I will try this approach.

Comment: No; that was specifically about batch writes to JDBC; to launch the job, you should use the Job Launching Gateway; see the [Spring Batch Integration documentation for more information](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html#launching-batch-jobs-through-messages).

Comment: Oh; I see, you mean use the INT-3364 technique *instead* of using a Batch Job; sorry; misunderstood.